# How were Krypto and Superboy able to fly after Luthor made our yellow Sun red?

Tags: dc, superman

In *Superman: War of Supermen* comics series, [Lex Luthor made our yellow Sun red](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/39722/931). All of Kryptonians including Superman & Supergirl started to lose their super powers & became very weak. But, later in the series, it was displayed that Krypto & Superboy were able to fly while the Sun was red.

Krypto is clearly a Kryptonian dog & Superboy inherits attributes of Superman because he is clone of Superman & Lex Luthor. Why was the red sun unable to affect Krypto & Superboy?

Comment: I admit that I'm not that well versed in the DC universe, but how is this not constructive? Sounds like a valid question to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conner Kent, aka Kon-El or Superboy uses a form of Telekenisis refered to as "Tactile Telekenisis" to approximate similar abilities to Superman.  According to wikipedia ["Another advantage of Superboy's telekinesis is that it does not use up his solar energy like Superman's powers."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conner_Kent#Powers.2C_abilities.2C_and_equipment)

However, after the 2003 retcon of his origin to include the concept that he was a hybrid clone of both Superman and Lex Luthor's genetic codes, and his gaining abilities more in line with those of Superman his tactile telekenisis was downplayed and almost completely non-existant.  This caused several inconsistencies from different writing staffs on the various books he appeared in (the Superman books and Teen Titans)  So while in the "Final Night" event when Earth's sun was put out and Superman lost his powers due to the lack of yellow radiation, Superboy did not.  But during the "Last Stand on Krypton" story arch he was trapped in the Bottle City of Kandor and he *did* lose his powers.  These inconsistancys have been "hand waived" away as [The effects of Super-Boy Prime punching reality.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_Crisis)

**TL;DR ANSWER:** Writer inconsistency

Comment: What about Krypto?

Comment: Conner could have extended his TK field around Krypto as long as they where in direct contact with each other.  Otherwise it's another writer inconsistency.

Answer (score 1):

I can't remember the exact details of that comic but here are some possibilities.
One possibility is that Superboy uses his tactile-telekinesis to fly him and Krypto around.
Another possibility is that they had a residual energy from the yellow sun to allow them to fly.