# Do Superboy and Krypto have the same weaknesses?

Tags: dc, krypton, superboy

It is well known that Superman loses his powers under a red sun.

However, a big plot point in "[The Spy from Outer Space](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt21398568/)" -- an episode of the 1966 cartoon, *The Adventures of Superboy* -- is Krypto being able to save Superboy when they travel to a system with a red sun.

How come Krypto's super powers weren't affected?

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/22820/how-were-krypto-and-superboy-able-to-fly-after-luthor-made-our-yellow-sun-red

Comment: The series were presumably of the silver age Superboy while the answer seems to be about some 2003 retcon

Comment: Indeed and hence why posted as a comment, rather than as an answer

Comment: I'm going to guess that there's no in-universe explanation, and that the out-of-universe explanation is that the writers weren't too concerned about tight plotting.