# How long do Superman's powers last without access to the Sun's radiation?

Tags: dc, superman, dc-animated-universe

Superman gets his powers from the radiation generated by our sun, but once he no longer has access to this radiation, how long do his powers last?

I'd be looking for examples from comics or the animated universe if possible.

Comment: Also, semi-dupe of http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/20154/has-superman-ever-been-attacked-by-changing-our-sun

Comment: @Richard ugh... we're declaring semi-dupes now too? What's the scope for something qualifying as semi-dupe?

Comment: a semi dupe is something that arguably isn't a true duplicate, but is *heavily* related. In this case, a detailed discussion of superman's abilities and their connection to sunlight.

Comment: @Richard _a semi dupe is something that arguably isn't a dupe_... seriously? Being pedantic is part of the rules now??

Comment: Being pedantic has always been part of the rules :-)